# How to make each CSV column different color

Tags: sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

[image]

How do I make coordinate system look so colorful?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This effect is done via a plugin, appropriately called [`rainbow_csv`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/rainbow_csv). It can be installed using Package Control.

Comment: Thank you very much, just another question. How can I do the column after each comma?

Comment: Like evenly spaced like in my reference image?

Comment: There should be a command in the Command Palette: `Rainbow CSV: Align CSV columns with spaces` that formats the CSV like shown in your example. I'd recommend reading through the whole page I linked in my answer, as it also includes full documentation.